# Telegram - how to create bot which create referral link to channel for every one user?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, referrals

If I need to create invite link to bot, I type *%reflink%* like in this [video](https://youtu.be/kYHY920cA2c?t=281).

But what may I to do if I want to create bot which create different referral link sto group for every one user?
Thank you for reply.

Comment: You can use [deeplink](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking) with users id as payload

Comment: And where can I see results (stats of referral and clicks...)?

Comment: You have to keep track of it